# Best way to do incremental update on Hive table from multiple files

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

The context is that I'm getting data from an API. I have the choice of exporting them as .csv (batching each hour) on file system or directly insert them via spark in hdfs.
So I have 2 scenarios I was thinking : 
1) Write first .csv on filesystem
* Run python scripts and store .csv in file system 
* Load in Hdfs into a single directory, use external hive table on the directory. 
* Create another hive table (e.g in parquet) and do insert overwrite from the external table to that table
2) Directly write data on hdfs
* Run spark job and store data as parquet files
* Create external hive table and add partition each time a new parquet directory is created.

The scenario 2 seems the cleanest way in term of monitoring (less jobs) but what about the numbers of partitions limit ? Should I restore the data as a single partition in the scenario 2) after a while ?
Is there a better way that I'm missing ?

Comment: So you are getting data every hour from an API and want to export it to HDFS ? In scenario 1 you want to ingest the data via a python script that puts the data on HDFS ? In scenario 2, Spark would be making the API calls ?

Comment: That's it indeed. I'm still a beginner with hive and storage format so dunno what's the cleanest way to do the incremental update.

Comment: Ok ! How much data are we talking about here ? Do your users need to have access to the newly ingested data every hour ? Or can they wait until the end of the day ?

Comment: The data aren't big at all, around 1 million rows per hour. And yes the users need to have access to the newly ingested data per hour. Thx

Comment: Use SqlContext to save data into Hive table directly.
dataFrame.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy(partitionCol).saveAsTable(hiveTable)

Comment: Yeah but what I prefer to work with parquet format ? Isn't more interesting to  use it as external table ? So that I'm not completely dependent on hive store directly. For the moment I'm using scenario 2 where I'm adding partition each time to the external table but not sure it's the cleanest way